# Flutter Realm list property

Tags: mongodb, flutter, dart, realm

I am using Flutter and Realm v1.3.0 with flexible sync to atlas.

I defined 2 models

```
@RealmModel()
class _Meeting {
  @PrimaryKey()
  @MapTo('_id')
  late ObjectId id;

  String? description;

  late List<_Event> events;
}

@RealmModel()
class _Event {
  @PrimaryKey()
  @MapTo('_id')
  late ObjectId id;

  late String name;

  @Backlink(#events)
  late Iterable<_Meeting> linkedMeeting;
}
```

in my screen `initState` I am fetching the meeting and the events for the meeting

```
    final meeting = realm.find<Meeting>(ObjectId.fromHexString(widget.meetingId));
    setState(() {
      _meeting = meeting;
      _events = meeting!.events.toList();
    });
```

then I try to display them in a list view

```
 ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: _events.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              final event = _events[index];
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(event.name) );
            },
          )
```

even though there are events associated to the meeting in the mongodb, the list in flutter is always empty. What am I missing here?
[image]

Comment: The question says `the list in flutter is always empty` however, what's shown in the screen shot is not empty. There's a single object at index 0 in the array. So..... ?

Comment: that is exactly my question why is the flutter list empty when there is data in the db? is it something to do with lazy loading of realm models?

Comment: Ah - the screenshot was confusing as seems that's what's in the array. It's always a good idea here on SO to do some troubleshooting before posting questions. For example, right after this statement `final meeting = realm.find` output the contents of `meeting` to console and see if it's what you expect. If not, that's the issue. If it is, add a line after `_events = meeting!.events.toList();` and output `_events` to console. Is it what you expect? Rinse and repeat until you narrow down where the error is. Once you have that info, update the question and we'll take a look.

Comment: Thanks Jay. Did all of that already. it is all empty.

Comment: If 'it is all empty' that would indicate the error is before attempting to display the list and goes back to this line `final meeting = realm.find<Meeting>(ObjectId.fromHexString(widget.meetingId));` or something prior not working. For example `widget.meetingId` could be nil, so this `ObjectId.fromHexString(` resolved to nothing, therefore, nothing is read. Sounds like you may want to do some further troubleshooting prior to that line to see where things go wrong.

Comment: No, the meeting object is fine. The data for that comes back but the events list is empty.

Comment: The question needs to include more accurate data and troubleshooting; comments are not good for that. Your comment stated "its all empty". But then "object is ok but events list is empty" - how do you know? What did you do to determine that the events list is empty? In other words, you could have a UI issue preventing them from showing. So are they part of the object, just not being displayed? What happened when the `meeting` object was output to console just after being read? Were there events? If it *outputs to console* with no events.. that shows the object has no events.